# How to use flex to make bootstrap panel with equal heigth

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am having problem styling my css using bootstrap. What I want is to display the list of data into a panel with equal height size like the courses in  udemy[image: udemy]

Here is my index

```
<div class="row-flex>
@foreach($courses['data'] as $course)
<div class="col-lg-3">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a href="{{ route('courses.show', $course['id'] ) }}">

            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>{{ $course['title'] }}</h4>
                <p>{{ $course['description'] }}</p>
                <p>{{ $course['fee'] }}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>      
@endforeach 
</div>
```

and my app.css

```
.flex, .flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: inline-block;
    flex:1 0 auto;
}

.panel {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   align-content:stretch; 
}

.panel-body {
   display: flex;
   flex-grow:1;
}
```

Can anyone help me on how to format the fetch values like the format of udemy.

Comment: ***Read before you tag:** Apache Flex (not to be confused with Flexbox)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

parent :

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

First childs:

```
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
```